# Integratation of erfc(a+bz)

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, error-function

Trying to solve $\int$erfc$(a+bz) dz$, but my answer doesn't seem to match what is given here: https://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/Erfc/21/ShowAll.html:

[image]

What I've got so far:

$\int\text{erfc}(a+bz) dz$

Let $u=a+bz$, $du=b dz$

$$\frac{1}{b} \int\text{erfc}(u) du = \frac{1}{b}(u\text{erfc}(u)- \frac{e^{u^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}})$$

Substituting back in

$$\frac{1}{b}((a+bz)\text{erfc}(a+bz)- \frac{e^{(a+bz)^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}) = \frac{a}{b}\text{erfc}(a+bz) + z \text{erfc}(a+bz) - \frac{e^{(a+bz)^2}}{b\sqrt{\pi}}$$

How does the $-\frac{a}{b}\text{erf}(a+bz)$ come in? From what I understand, $-\text{erf}(z) = \text{erfc}(z) - 1$, which I don't have.

Comment: Ah, realise now that I left out the constant, and that is likely where the -1 is coming from. Don't quite see the benefit of writing -erf(a+bz) over erfc(a+bz) though.

Comment: Another question is how to derive $\mathrm{\int erfc(y) dy}$. You could probably just do integration by parts of erfc(y) and 1. Tell me if you want the photo gone, but it helps to put everything together.